# Scroll function not loading the next 50 items from an external json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The Idea is to load only 50 items at a time to help with loading the page.
I have the code that will load the first 50 items form a json file.

I then want to load the next 50 when the user scrolls halfway down the page and keep going tell there is no more items to load.
This is what I have so far.

```
//This loads the first 50 items from external Json file. No issue here
$(window).load(function(){
  var picarioAPI = "https://sdlbytheyard.picarioxpo.com/xpo/api/v1/designs/search/Customizable&Customizable/?apiKey=f02ac05d0a664db08274c7d7c4c0b594&skip=0&take=50";
  var newtext = document.getElementById("DeisgnLibraryPopupButtom").innerHTML
  $.getJSON(picarioAPI, function (json) {
    var text = "";
    for (i in json.values)
    for (var j in json.values[i].labels) {
      if (json.values[i].labels[j].name == "Show") {
      // This is for a popup function.
      var b = 'data-options=&#123;&#34;src&#34;&#58;&#32;&#34;#hidden-content-3'+json.values[i].id+'&#34;&#44;&#32;&#34;touch&#34;&#58;&#32;false&#125;';
      text += '<div class="prod" style="float:left;"><a data-fancybox ' + b + ' href="javascript:;" onclick="test()"><img class="lazyload" src="' + json.values[i].displayUrl + '"><p class="title">' + json.values[i].name + '</p></a></div><div style="display: none;max-width:500px;" id="hidden-content-3'+json.values[i].id+'"><img class="lazyload" src="' + json.values[i].displayUrl + '" data-height="'+json.values[i].height+'"data-width="'+json.values[i].width+'"data-url="'+json.values[i].displayUrl+'"data-full="'+json.values[i].renderUrl +'"data-name="'+json.values[i].name+'"><p class="title">' + json.values[i].name + '</p>' + newtext + '</div>';
      document.getElementById("design1").innerHTML = text;
      }
    };
  });
});
```

I then load a scroll function to load the next 50 items and so on.  I use the number to add 50 items to the end of the Json file API

```
//This is the part I'm not getting correct.
var number = 0;
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('body').height() / 2) {
    number++;
    // I use the number to dynamically load the next 50 items as the user scrolls.
    var total = number + 50;
    var picarioAPI = 'https://sdlbytheyard.picarioxpo.com/xpo/api/v1/designs/search/Customizable&Customizable/?apiKey=f02ac05d0a664db08274c7d7c4c0b594&skip='+total+'&take=50';
    var newtext = document.getElementById("DeisgnLibraryPopupButtom").innerHTML
    $.getJSON(picarioAPI, function (json) {
      var text = "";
      for (i in json.values)
      for (var j in json.values[i].labels) {
        if (json.values[i].labels[j].name == "Show") {
        //this is for a popup function
        var b = 'data-options=&#123;&#34;src&#34;&#58;&#32;&#34;#hidden-content-3'+json.values[i].id+'&#34;&#44;&#32;&#34;touch&#34;&#58;&#32;false&#125;';
        text += '<div class="prod" style="float:left;"><a data-fancybox ' + b + ' href="javascript:;" onclick="test()"><img class="lazyload" src="' + json.values[i].displayUrl + '"><p class="title">' + json.values[i].name + '</p></a></div><div style="display: none;max-width:500px;" id="hidden-content-3'+json.values[i].id+'"><img class="lazyload" src="' + json.values[i].displayUrl + '" data-height="'+json.values[i].height+'"data-width="'+json.values[i].width+'"data-url="'+json.values[i].displayUrl+'"data-full="'+json.values[i].renderUrl +'"data-name="'+json.values[i].name+'"><p class="title">' + json.values[i].name + '</p>' + newtext + '</div>';
        document.getElementById("design1").innerHTML += document.getElementById("design1").innerHTML + text;
        }
      };
    });
  };
});
```

The issue is when I scroll halfway down the page it will start to load all 2000 items instead of just the next 50. 
Any help would be great.

Comment: just a point you may want to fix ... the first 50 will load, then the first "addition" will have skip=51, the next time the load happens, skip=52 - I think you want `var total = number * 50;` not `var total = number + 50;`

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: on to your issue - if you check the **developer** tools console, are you getting all 2000 items in one request, or are there multiple requests being made - if it's all in one request, the issue is that the server is sending them all, because (apart from the issue in my first comment) the code looks OK (as much as I can tell because the formatting is virtually unreadable)

Comment: `That is correct` - what is? skip=51 then skip=52 ... or do you mean my correction is correct :p

Comment: It should be var total = number * 50;.

Comment: The server is sending multiple requests at once.  How do I only send one?

Answer (score 0):

unless you stop scrolling EXACTLY when you've reached half way, you'll be getting multiple triggers of `scroll` - you need to introduce some flag to indicate that a request is in flight, and ignore the scroll event until the new data is loaded

```
var inflight = false;
var number = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (!inflight && $(window).scrollTop() > $('body').height() / 2) {
        inflight = true;
        number++;
        // I use the number to dynamically load the next 50 items as the user scrolls.
        var total = number + 50;
        var picarioAPI = 'https://sdlbytheyard.picarioxpo.com/xpo/api/v1/designs/search/Customizable&Customizable/?apiKey=f02ac05d0a664db08274c7d7c4c0b594&skip=' + total + '&take=50';
        var newtext = document.getElementById("DeisgnLibraryPopupButtom").innerHTML
        $.getJSON(picarioAPI, function(json) {
            var text = "";
            for (i in json.values) {
                for (var j in json.values[i].labels) {
                    if (json.values[i].labels[j].name == "Show") {
                        //this is for a popup function
                        var b = 'data-options=&#123;&#34;src&#34;&#58;&#32;&#34;#hidden-content-3' + json.values[i].id + '&#34;&#44;&#32;&#34;touch&#34;&#58;&#32;false&#125;';
                        text += '<div class="prod" style="float:left;"><a data-fancybox ' + b + ' href="javascript:;" onclick="test()"><img class="lazyload" src="' + json.values[i].displayUrl + '"><p class="title">' + json.values[i].name + '</p></a></div><div style="display: none;max-width:500px;" id="hidden-content-3' + json.values[i].id + '"><img class="lazyload" src="' + json.values[i].displayUrl + '" data-height="' + json.values[i].height + '"data-width="' + json.values[i].width + '"data-url="' + json.values[i].displayUrl + '"data-full="' + json.values[i].renderUrl + '"data-name="' + json.values[i].name + '"><p class="title">' + json.values[i].name + '</p>' + newtext + '</div>';
                        document.getElementById("design1").innerHTML += document.getElementById("design1").innerHTML + text;
                    }
                }
            }
            inflight = false;
        });
    }
});
```